# Avoid using deprecated vaadin 6 methods in vaadin 7

Tags: java, methods, vaadin, deprecated

I am on a Project update from version `vaadin 6` to `vaadin 7`. In the `vaadin 7` version is used to a large extent the method [getPaintable()](http://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.rc2/docs/api/com/vaadin/client/ApplicationConnection.html#getPaintable%28com.vaadin.client.UIDL%29) from the class ApplicationConnection. Nevertheless it is deprecated in `vaadin 7` . After examining the `api` and the [official tutorial](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/gwt.shared-state.html) I have not detected and understood by what method or combination of methods it is replaced. If I want for example to do:

```
ComponentConnector paintable = this.client.getPaintable(uidl);
```

How can I excecute the above statement using excusively `vaadin 7 (not deprecated) api`?

**Update:**

The answer certifies my suspect that the method in `ApplicationConnection` [getConnector(java.lang.String connectorId, int connectorType)](http://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.rc2/docs/api/com/vaadin/client/ApplicationConnection.html#getConnector%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)  should be used instead, but it is still missing, what is the int type `connectorType` and how one gets it. Any suggestion?

**Update 2:**

The replacement suggested in the answer seems reasonable and it might work but my worry is:
Should we use generally UIDL class in vaadin 7? I have the impression that the method `updateFromUIDL(UIDL uidl, ApplicationConnection client)`should not be called in vaadin 7. How can we the get `uidl.getId()` , `uidl.getTag()`. I reckon also that `uidl.getId()` should be replaced by the method in `AbstractConnector` [getConnectorId()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/client/ui/AbstractConnector.html#getConnectorId%28%29). Am I right?

Comment: Hmm, this one is truly missing a comment.

Comment: There seems to be type in the second sentence. It should be vaadin 6, shouldn't it?

Comment: Re Update2: No, you shouldn't use UIDL. Have a look at the link in my answer: Vaadin 7 changes the general mechanism for Client-Server interaction of widgets.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

After looking at the implementation of the deprecated getPaintable method, you should be able replace it with

```
ComponentConnector paintable = (ComponentConnector) getConnector(uidl.getId(),
            Integer.parseInt(uidl.getTag()));
```

**But don't forget that this can be only a intermediate step. [Vaadin 7 changes the general mechanism for Client-Server interaction of widgets](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Migrating+from+Vaadin+6+to+Vaadin+7#section-Migrating+from+Vaadin+6+to+Vaadin+7-ClientSideWidgets):**

> The old mechanism with UIDL, paintContent() and changeVariables() is still there for a while to ease migration, but it is recommended to update your components to the new mechanisms, which also tend to result in much cleaner code. Using the old mechanisms requires implementing LegacyComponent.

If you compare the integration diagrams of [Vaadin 6](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/architecture.client-side.html) with [Vaadin 7](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/gwt.html), you will see how the general integration mechanism have changed.

**Original Answer:**

**[Vaadin dev ticket: Deprecate ApplicationConnection.getPaintable(UIDL)](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/8439)**

Description:

Functionality from getPaintable(UIDL) should be moved to getPaintable(String paintableId) and getPaintable(UIDL) should be deprecated

Change Log:

#8439 Deprecated ApplicationConnect.getPaintable(UIDL) and added getConnector(String id, String connectorType) instead

Comment: Yes, I have suspected it, but I still do not know how to pass the connectorType argument. It is an int type. How can someone get it?

Comment: Helpful your suggestion, but it evokes a new Update!

Comment: That should be the same code that is called when you call the deprecated API (see: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/client/src/com/vaadin/client/ApplicationConnection.java Row 2869). Hmm.

Comment: Do you mean that the class ApplicationConnection is anyway deprecated in vaadin 7? How can we go around it since some methods of it (i.e. getConnectorId()) are still necessary?

Comment: No. It means that the Client Architecture of Vaadin 7 differs from them one in Vaadin 6 and you have to do more than only find a replacement for this one call. I will update the answer with some more hints.

Comment: Of course I have to do more. I have read the relevant instructions but they are focused only on adead simple case and on the point of Paintable replacement I got really stuck.